# joomla components donation

Tags: joomla1.5

can any one please show me a component that can manage a donation offer many way to pay the donation and show them in the front end of joomla . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple module that allows your visitors to donate money](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/donations/4661) to you.

Check out ["Donations" category in Joomla extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/donations) for alternative modules